# sort du -sh by size in human readable

Tags: sorting, du

with the command

```
du -sh *
```

I get the summary of files in MB,GB, etc.
If I use

```
du -s * | sort -nk1
```

I get the summary sort by size.
How I can get the summary sort by size in MB, GB, etc?

#### Edit

the OS is ubuntu

Comment: You didn't mention the OS and/or version of sort you're using.  If it's GNU sort replace the -n with a -h. So "du -sh * | sort -hk1,1"

Comment: @tink you comment solve the question

Comment: Now I wish I had made it an answer ;D

Comment: @tink with you comment make a answer for close this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using GNU sort, try the following:

```
du -sh * | sort -hk1,1
```